# Rails 3 - AutoComplete with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm interested in using the Rails 3 AutoComplete plugin for jQuery but the one tutorial provided doesn't match my use case. Hoping for some help...

Plug In: http://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-app

I have a Permissions Controller where people can add team members.

On the Permissions SHOW view I want to show a autocomplete for user's....

Here's what I did:
Added all the required JS in the header, loaded fine

In the permissions controller:

```
autocomplete :user, :name
```

In the config.rb:

```
get 'permission/autocomplete_user_name'
```

Then in the Permissions SHOW View

```
<%= form_tag do %>
<%=text_field_tag 'name', '', :autocomplete => permission_autocomplete_user_name_path %>
<% end %>
```

But nothing happens. No errors, and no jquery autocomplete action or activity in FireBug. Suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find the answer for this? I have the problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the config/routes.rb file, and add:

get 'permission/autocomplete_user_name'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make permission in the config.rb file as well as in the show view plural. Try making it permissions